# Trying to Implement FTP Port Command on Server: Port in use

Tags: java, ftp, network-programming

Not sure why I am getting that stack trace on eclipse when I am trying to setup the socket to the port that my client is requesting.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're trying to setup two server sockets on the same port on the same computer. which you can't

Comment: Why when I use PASV it works?

Comment: I can't answer that as i don't know what `PASV` does and what it means

Comment: Don't post pictures of text here. Wastes your time, our bandwidth. Post the text.

Comment: Its really hard to copy and paste stuff in here. the format is terrible and sometimes I have to slowly indent the fields to get the layout I want.

Comment: @EJP I'll just delete this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client is requesting that you are connecting to the address/port given in the PORT command. That means you must create a connection to the client (ClientSocket) but instead you are waiting for a connection from the client (ServerSocket). With PASV mode it is different, because there you wait for a connection from the client (ServerSocket).

The "Address already in use" message is caused by the fact, that you are trying an FTP connection to localhost. That is the client is already bound to the IP:port given in the PORT command and waiting for connection but you wrongly try to create a ServerSocket on exact the same port on the same system  - which is not possible and causes the error message.

Comment: I see I will try that. So on the server I will make a Socket to the address given by Port command from the client. and do not wait for accept?